# I cant get the value of "postId" and "Post" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I try to get the value of 'postId it shows undefined', and when I try to get the Post component it shows 'cannot destructure of the property title because props.posts is undefined', what is the problem I didn't get it. The Github link is "https://github.com/saakeeb/material-ui-react".

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import FakeData from '../FakeData/FakeData';
import Post from '../Post/Post';

const PostDetails = () => {
    const {postIdNum} = useParams();
    const postId = FakeData.find(pd => pd.id=== postIdNum);
    console.log('postId', postId);
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{postIdNum} no Post details</h3>
            <Post postId={postId}></Post>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PostDetails;
```

Comment: perhaps nothing in `FakeData` has a `id:` that matches `postIdNum` returned from `useParams()` ... there's so much unknown in this question - what is the value of `postIdNum` in the object returned by `useParams()`

Comment: Can you show your `<Route>` component in the question?

Comment: NO fakedata has id value, here is my github link would you please check and answer, https://github.com/saakeeb/material-ui-react

Comment: Also, strictly looking at your error only, it seems that the problem is in the `Post` component rather than `PostDetails`, have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I get the value of 'post component' from the parent component Home.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postIdNum` retrieved from the useParams() is a string value, and because of the comparison of an integer value with a string value, the find() returns the value undefined.

On converting the string value `postIdNum` to an integer value, using parseInt(), solves the problem.

Also, in the FakeData.json there is no object property called `key`, so comparing values with an undefined property will also result in an undefined return.

Try executing the code,

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import FakeData from '../FakeData/FakeData';
import Post from '../Post/Post';

const PostDetails = () => {
    const {postIdNum} = useParams();
    const postId = FakeData.find((pd) => pd.id === parseInt(postIdNum));
    console.log('postId', postId);
    console.log(Object.values(postIdNum));
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{postIdNum} no Post details</h3>
        <Post posts={postId}></Post>
      </div>
    );
};

export default PostDetails;
```

Comment: Thank you Muskan Bhai, I am getting the of postId but still "post " component showing 'cannot restructure property title of pros.posts'

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked perfectly for me. You can check if there is some other problem with running the code. [Link to the image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36980003/100623762-9bd4ab80-3348-11eb-8b0a-e46ccaaa72ef.png).
Just for information, I am a girl :).

Comment: Thank you. I have figure out there is a typing mistake in my vscode. And sorry for mention you 'Bhai', Apu.